# Needs clarification for closing gracefully the Android application

Tags: android, android-intent, activity-finish

I want to close the application **gracefully**. I found two methods.

**1. Using Intents:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Documentation says:

> Activity Action: Start as a main entry point, does not expect to receive data.
>
> Category Home: This is the home activity, that is the first activity that is displayed when the device boots.

**2. Using Finish:**

```
finish()
```

Documentation says:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.

What is the best method or professional method for closing the Android application? Both close the application but `finish()` removes the app from cache (App not in recent activities) while using `intent`, cache does not deleted. Should cache remove from the cell on finishing the activity?

Comment: "What is the best method or professional method for closing the Android application?" -- not doing it at all. "but finish() removes the app from cache" -- no, it does not, as an activity is not an app. "App not in recent activities" -- `finish()` does not remove the app from the overview screen (a.k.a., recent-tasks list), if that is what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is the proper one, as it's said in the official doc :

> Call this when your **activity is done and should be closed**. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().

The App is a succession of activities. Closing the app means closing the first activity of the app.

The first method you described in your Post (**1. Using Intents**) seems to be a workaround; it's similar to when the physical **home button** of your device is pressed. It lets the activity to the **back stack** and launch the Home (First) activity of the device.